# UINavigationBar appearance, setBackgroundImag issue

Tags: ios, objective-c, uinavigationcontroller, uinavigationbar

in my appDelegate in `didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:` i used this code to set a local navigator controller

```
[[UINavigationBar appearance] setBackgroundImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"myNav.png"] forBarMetrics:(UIBarMetricsDefault)];
```

its works well. but now i want to change one of my cotroller's navigation bar and i'm not able to do that. its always show the navigator i defined in appDelegate.

there is any way to get over it? or should i define a navigatorBackGround for each of my viewControllers to achieve this?

Comment: Did the solution work?

Answer (score 0):

For iOs 7, the navigation bar uses the `tintColor` property. Try `[self.navigationController.navigationBar setTintColor:[UIColor redColor]];`

Comment: I forgot to mention, i want to change the image with backGroundColor. tried this [self.navigationController.navigationBar setBackgroundColor:[UIColor whiteColor]]; withOut success.

Comment: Is this for iOS 6 or 7?

Comment: [self.navigationController.navigationBar setBarTintColor:[UIColor redColor]]; is for navigation color, i tried it with no success.

Comment: Oh ya you're right, that isn't for background color.